# Emojis Compat is not showing emojis

Tags: android, emoji

Hi i am using [EmojisCompat](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat#java) library

This is the response i am getting from server, i am getting require required retrofit models and setting it into adapter:

```
{"text":"value \\u270c\\u270c"}
```

And in my adapter i am setting text view like this

```
tvDescription.setText(EmojiCompat.get().process(model.value()))
```

Still the emojis are not processed `tvDescription` is `EmojiAppCompatTextView`

content displayed in `EmojiAppCompatTextView` is just: `value \u270c\u270c`